# Javascript: converting string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, calculator

This is one of my function for a calculator project. First I needed to convert the input string into an array, and do the operation later. (assuming that input has only numbers and '+' sign for now.

My question here is, how do I improve this code? What are the other ways to deal with this problem? (Time complexity, cleanness, shorter code.......whatever)

```js
function convertArray(input) {
  let array = [];
  let num = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input.charAt(i) == '+') {
      array.push(input.charAt(i));
    } else {
      do {
        num += input.charAt(i);
        i++;
      } while (i < input.length && input.charAt(i) !== '+');
      array.push(num);
      num = "";
      i--;
    }
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(convertArray("10+2+3000+70+1"));
```

Comment: do you have some inoputs and outputs? does the code work?

Comment: Not about making sense, more about being on topic.
Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @NinaScholz Run the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split with a group. this add the group as well to the array.

For other calculation signs, you could add them to the brackets.

```js
const convertArray = string => string.split(/([+])/);

console.log(convertArray("10+2+3000+70+1"));
```

Comment: Arrgh. Took me several minutes playing with exec to do this!

Comment: At least mine can see if it is an operator or not

Answer (score 0):

It seems the complexity must have something to do with your wish to determing operators. In your code you just push them all into the array. To do that is like

```js
const re = /((\d+)|([^\d]+))/g
const convertArray = str => {
  let match, arr=[];
  while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    arr.push(match[1]) // here you can determine if you have an operator
    console.log(match[1],"Operator?",!/^\d+$/.test(match[1]))
  }
  return arr
}
const str = "10+2+3000+70+1";

console.log(convertArray(str));
```